# Is a python dict's len() atomic with respect to the GIL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

I'm asking about CPython, python2.7. Say I have a `dict`, and a few threads that will insert values from time to time by calling `add()`:

```
d = {}
dlock = threading.Lock()
def add(key, value):
    with dlock:
        d[key] = value
```

Is it safe to get the size of the dict from a separate thread without grabbing the lock, relying just on the GIL?

```
def count():
    return len(d)
```

Assuming that I don't care about getting precisely the correct value, just any value that was correct at some point during `count()`.

Comment: Dicts don't have an `insert` method.

Comment: user2357112: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: That lock looks a little pointless. `d[key] = value` is already atomic w.r.t. the GIL.

Comment: If you call `count()` and then based on its return value do something with your dict, then you need to protect that whole section, no matter if the `len` call is atomic or not. Protecting only the body of count would be rather pointless, as between `len(d)` returning and `count()` returning `d` _could_ have been mutated by another thread.

Comment: mata: Yes, I know that. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it, but yeah, the GIL will protect that. There's no opportunity for the GIL to be released during the `len` call.

Comment: Why would you not recommend it?

Comment: @Benno: It ties your program to CPython, and relying on the GIL makes it hard to tell what operations you need to be atomic and how much the GIL actually protects.

Comment: Also, someone might pass in something that's not a `dict` whose `__len__()` is implemented in Python and isn't atomic.